# Oracle Alert Response Set

Tags: response, alert, erp, oracle-ebs

I would like to create a Response Set for Oracle Alerts. But no luck finding any tutorial on that. Can somebody provide some examples on how to do so?
My idea is to let user reply the record ID, then I can update the record status through SQL action. Is this doable?

[image]

Comment: What product/ application is this?  I'm pretty sure that this is not related (directly) to an Oracle database though there may be an Oracle database on the back end.

Comment: This is an Oracle ERP R12 application.